# Wordpress Custom Post Type which creates Pages

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way that a Custom Post Type can create Pages?
Or is there a other way to achieve this?

Basically I want a "Event" Custom Post Type, which has these pages: date, reviews, images.
The permalink structure should be /event-YEAR/PAGENAME.
Also every page has to be editable in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old post but it sounds like it handles exactly what you're asking. http://www.placementedge.com/blog/create-post-sub-pages/

Reading through it, still seems to be relevant for the most part.

Essentially you're:

- Setting up your custom post type with specific settings
- Setup custom rewrite rules for your post type
- Adding custom fields to the post type for the sub pages (I would use Advanced Custom Fields)
- Creating specific page template files that display the custom fields automatically